# Getting signal 11 (SIGSEGV) when using libcurl in multithreaded Program

Tags: c++, multithreading, curl, libcurl, rhel

**I did this**
From google I found out we should build libcurl by providing --enable-threaded-resolver but it didn't help, I am still seeing the segfault
I also tried setting the NoSignal option, but that also didn't help.
From logs of program it seems one thread hungs up when calling perform function (of curlpp library ie we have curlpp::Easy request; and it hungs when we do request.perform in one thread) 
Also, the issue does not appear at every run and is specific to linux , works fine on MAC OS and Windows.

**curl/libcurl version** 
I tried 7.21.2 and 7.66 version (7.66 with --enable-threaded-resolver )

**Error** 
With 7.21.2 version , I was getting 
==8866==
==8866== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8866== Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==8866== at 0x551FCDD: _IO_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==8866== by 0x5520E81: _IO_default_uflow (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==8866== by 0x5513C33: _IO_getline_info (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==8866== by 0x551D6FC: fgets_unlocked (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==8866== by 0xF57D5AE: internal_getent (in /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so)
==8866== by 0xF57E7E2: _nss_files_gethostbyname4_r (in /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so)
==8866== by 0x558A1B3: gaih_inet.constprop.8 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==8866== by 0x558B553: getaddrinfo (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==8866== by 0xCB6E013: Curl_getaddrinfo_ex (in /usr/local/qubole/libquboleodbc.so)
==8866== by 0xCB6AE65: Curl_getaddrinfo (in /usr/local/qubole/libquboleodbc.so)
==8866== by 0xCB51CF4: Curl_resolv (in /usr/local/qubole/libquboleodbc.so)
==8866== by 0xCB51FBA: Curl_resolv_timeout (in /usr/local/qubole/libquboleodbc.so)

With 7.66 version (with --enable-threaded-resolver) , I started getting
==11063==
==11063== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==11063== Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==11063== at 0x551FCDD: _IO_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==11063== by 0x5520E81: _IO_default_uflow (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==11063== by 0x5513C33: _IO_getline_info (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==11063== by 0x551D6FC: fgets_unlocked (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==11063== by 0xFDAA5AE: internal_getent (in /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so)
==11063== by 0xFDAB7E2: _nss_files_gethostbyname4_r (in /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so)
==11063== by 0x558A1B3: gaih_inet.constprop.8 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==11063== by 0x558B553: getaddrinfo (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==11063== by 0xCB7D2E3: Curl_getaddrinfo_ex (in /usr/local/qubole/libquboleodbc.so)
==11063== by 0xCB585C0: getaddrinfo_thread (in /usr/local/qubole/libquboleodbc.so)
==11063== by 0xCB8474A: curl_thread_create_thunk (in /usr/local/qubole/libquboleodbc.so)
==11063== by 0xF391EA4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)

The above is seen when I use Valgrind.

operating system
RHEL 7.7

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you linking with `-lpthread`?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson No we are not linking with -lpthread, In our code, we are using std::thread ("#include <thread>").

Comment: `#include <thread>` requires `-lpthread`

Comment: We have `-lboost_thread` option present and I also tried adding `-lpthread` but still getting the same error (2nd error mentioned).
@ThomasSablik
@JoachimIsaksson

Comment: @ThomasSablik
@AlanBirtles The issue was with Glibc library which got fixed in the later version.
Specifically with this function `getaddrinfo (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)`.
We were dynamically linking Glibc, I wonder Is it advised to statically link glic working version to avoid such cases or Glibc library on that machine should be upgraded?

Comment: You can deliver your own glibc with your program